# CSS, trying to make hyperlink align to bottom

Tags: css

I'm guessing there's a basic error in here, but I don't understand why my bottom positioning is being overridden. `.link` is outside of the body.

```
body {
  font-family: Century Gothic, Arial;
  background-color: #836FFF; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 910px;
  background-color: #6A5ACD;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #473C8B;
}

.t1 {
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto; 
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #473C8B; 
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.link {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't really have anchor tags outside the `body` tag.

Comment: try putting `position:relative` in `body{}` if i'm understanding you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your link is absolutely positioned it should be within a wrapper that is position:relative. Then set your wrappers size and padding. And the .link will be positioned within the wrapper absolutely. So bottom left 5 based on the wrappers position. If you want it at the very bottom do bottom 0 left or right 0

Answer (score 0):

2 things...if you want the link to always be at the bottom of the visible browser, use position: fixed. If you truly want the link to be at the bottom of the page, it depends on the parent elements. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: ^ much better link for css positioning